# I don't understand the meaning of the sentence in bold clearly?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> The reunion had lasted a week. As they packed for home, his father, in a far too offhand
>   way, had suggested they visit Chig’s grandmother. “We might as well drop in on her and my brother’s.”
>   So, instead of going north, they just had gone farther south, had just entered her house. And Chig had a suspicion now that the reunion had only been an excuse to drive south, that his father had been heading to this house all the time.
>   His father had never talked much about his family, with the exception of his brother, GL,
>   who seemed part con man, part practical joker and part Don Juan; **he had spoken of GL with the kind of indulgence he would have shown a cute, but ill-behaved and potentially dangerous, five-year-old.**
>   Chig’s father had left home when he was fifteen. When asked why, he would answer: “I wanted to go to school. They didn’t have a Negro high school at home, so I went up to Knoxville and lived with a cousin and went to school.

Dose it mean that He talked about his brother with abnegation like someone who would have shown his emotions toward a cute, but ill-behaved and potentially dangerous, five-year-old?

(GL is Doctor Charles 's brother and Doctor Charles after so long wanted to visit his family)

Source: Based on a short story named: A Visit to Grandmother by William Melvin Kelley.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't exactly mean he *described* his brother as being *a cute (but ill-behaved and potentially dangerous) five-year-old*. Simply that *the way the father spoke about GL* was "indulgent, forgiving" - showing the same *kind* of indulgence that he would have shown to that kind of 5-year-old. You might think there's some implication that GL is in fact *"cute, but ill-behaved and potentially dangerous"*, but that's not explicitly stated. And it's a racing certainty GL isn't actually a 5-year-old.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I chenged my understanding in my question. am I right in this way?

Comment: It doesn't ***actually*** say anything directly at all about GL himself. All it says is that GL's ***father*** talked about him "indulgently, fondly" (the way he might have talked about that kind of 5-year-old, as I already said). A mother might talk to her baby they way she would talk to her cat, but that doesn't mean she thinks (or is saying) that her baby is a cat. Arguably it's ***implied*** that GL is at least ***like*** a *cute, but ill-behaved and potentially dangerous, five-year-old*, but that's not explicitly stated (and of course we ***know*** GL isn't really a 5-year-old).

Comment: Lots of thanks for your answer. You mean he talked about his brother fondly like someone who would have shown his emotions toward a cute, but ill-behaved and potentially dangerous, five-year-old.

Comment: The main clue is: to be indulgent towards someone.